# Updating JPA Entity Model

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have an application that is running on Google App Engine that uses JPA. I imagine that at some point, as the application evolves, new attributes will be added to the java classes, requiring an update to the jpa model. How are changes like this generally handled once an application is in production?

For example, lets say I add a new field (foo) to my class (bar), and I say that foo isn't nullable. During the course of a transaction, the EntityManager reads in an old bar object(before the foo was added), updates another field, and tries to commit the change, and an exception happens. That is something I would want to guard against.

In general, is there a best practice for updating the jpa model after it's been put into production to avoid constraint conflicts for older objects that have been persisted?

Comment: you mean GAE using "Datastore" or appengine-sql (i.e mysql) ? If the former then why is Hibernate tagged?

Comment: My mistake, didn't mean to tag hibernate since Google uses their own implementation of JPA. Yes, storing the data in the datastore using JPA

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately updating the model like that is not trivial in gae. You'll have to either update all existing entities or create an "update on demand" so that this entities don't fail your new conditions.

Adding a not nullable field for example forces you to update your entities beforehand as JPA will not allow you to do so afterwards.